# Throwing exceptions from Mockito mock

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

Something tells me I'm doing something wrong...it shouldn't be this hard.

I have a class that relies on some inner class. I'm creating that inner through a protected method so that I can override that in a test to provide a mock. I understand that to get a Mockito mock object to throw an exception from a void method, I have to use doThrow.

But my problem is that the compiler complains that the call to Mockito.doThrow() is throwing RuntimeException...so then I have to add a throws clause to the method setting up the mock.  Is that a bug in Mockito itself?  doThrow is declaring something that should happen in the future, but not during the setup of the mock.

My OuterClass looks like...

```
public class OuterClass {
  protected InnerClass inner;
  protected void createInner() { inner = new InnerClass(); }
  protected doSomething() {
    try {
      inner.go();
    } catch (RuntimeException re) {
      throw new MyException("computer has caught fire");
    }
  }
}
```

And my test code looks like...

```
@Test(expected = MyException.class)
public void testSomething() {
  OuterClass outer = new TestOuterClass();
  outer.doSomething();
}

public static class TestOuterClass extends OuterClass {
  @Override
  public void createInner() {
    InnerClass mock = Mockito.mock(InnerClass.mock);
    Mockito.doThrow(new RuntimeException("test")).when(mock).go();  // PROBLEM
    inner = mock;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please could you check that the compiler really is complaining about a `RuntimeException`?

The thing about `RuntimeException` is that it shouldn't matter at compile time. I suspect the compiler is actually complaining about `MyException` - which I presume is a checked exception, noticed by the compiler, which is thrown by the `doSomething()` method. You should be able to simply add the `throws MyException` to the test method, which will then be caught by the test runner. Since it's expected, the test runner will pass.

Comment: Yeah, my mistake.  What it's really complaining about is MyException, as you suggested. InnerClass.go() is declared to throw MyException (I left that out in my code above). But OuterClass.createInner() does not. I think it's not the Mockito.doThrow() that's causing the problem...it's the call to .go() on the end that's doing it. So even though @test method already declares throws MyException, this doesn't help.

Comment: Ah ha! I figured it out.

I just need to wrap my doThrow...go() stuff in a try/catch to hide it from the create method. But when the create method is called, it does actually call the mock, and it does get and trap the RuntimeException.